# Append Multiple Existing Queries

Tags: powerquery

Pulling my hair out on this one...

I'm trying to consolidate multiple connection only queries (querying Sharepoint Excel and csv Files). Each file has a unique transform, therefore the need for a unique query for each. This works beautifully in connection only queries and dump to table for testing.

The way I've done it so far was with these key lines:

```
let
Source = #sections,
Section1 = Source[Section1],
#"QueryList" = Record.ToTable(Section1),
#"Test Errors" = //Omitted tests for error queries
#"Remove Errors" = //Omitted removes error queries
#"FilterOut" = //Omitted filters out queries I don't want
#"Expanded Value" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"FilterOut", "Value", {...fields...}, {...fieldsagain...}), ...yada yada rest of code...
```

It's merging beautifully... BUT it's only returning the data loaded in cache for previews, and NOT the full data refresh (even with Refresh All button, and via VBA).

I've searched for solutions as much as I could, bounced ideas off colleagues and not much additional advice other than setting queries to:

- Disable Background refresh
- Refresh on Open

Really hoped this would solve the problem... it didn't.

So re-looking at the Append Query, and trying to append queries with an "Each" clause from a list... but getting errors:

```
    let

//Set the Header Row
#"BaseTable" = //Create the headers ... side-step query firewall issues

//Get List of Query Names
Source = #sections,
Section1 = Source[Section1],
#"QueryList" = Record.ToTable(Section1),
#"Test Errors" = //Omitted tests for error queries
#"Remove Errors" = //Omitted removes error queries
#"FilterOut" = //Omitted filters out queries I don't want
//Custom field to get the query names just right
#"CustomName" //Custom field [QUERY_N] to get the query names just right
#"Removed Other Columns1" = Table.SelectColumns(#"CustomName",{"QUERY_N"}),
//Final table with a single column listing all the query names
QueryListing = #"Removed Other Columns1",

//Appending
#"Appended Query" = Table.Combine({#"BaseTable", each QueryListing}) in#"Appended Query"
```

Now I get the error:

```
Expression.Error: We cannot convert a value of type Function to type Table. Details: Value=Function Type=Type
```

Tried to patch up the query names with an alternate naming to make sure it's not a stray character set in the listing bit:

```
#"CustomName" //Custom field [QUERY_N] to get the query names just right,
#"Removed Other Columns1" = Table.SelectColumns(#"CustomName",{"QUERY_N"}),
QueryListing = Table.ToList(#"Removed Other Columns1"),

//Appending
#"Appended Query" = Table.Combine({#"BaseTable", each "#" & """" & QueryListing & """"})
```

But nope, not a string error, same error message after refresh.

Any ideas on how I can get this to work?

Answer (score 1):

`each` makes a function, as `each ...` is a shorter way of writing `(_) => ...`. You can combine two lists by using the `&` operator instead.

If you have the table of query values from drilling down into `#sections`, you should use those values directly instead of getting their names. If `QueryValues` is the name of the step with a one-column table of your table values, and that column name is `Column`, then this should work:

`Table.Combine({BaseTable} & QueryListing[Column])`

For the first approach, how do you know it is missing fields? Is it missing columns, or does it have all of the columns but not all of the rows?

Comment: Luckily all the columns are there, but it's missing records. I did a deep dive to check which records, and confirmed it's only pulling info in the cache. i.e. for the query only queries, it's not refreshing them when doing the combine.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I'll try the approach outlined here, and come back with the results.

Comment: Managed to get the queries to combine using your method here. The problem still persists, it's not refreshing the full connection only queries that are referenced, it's only sending the first records in the cache during preview. After clearing the cache and running a full refresh, I'm now getting NO records in final result, but still some in the Editor.

Comment: We need to narrow down which step could be causing this. Could you extract some of the steps into separate queries and then fill those queries to the sheet? You can separate the steps by right clicking on a step and choosing Extract Previous.

Comment: Each query works perfectly on it's own, and when I manually create an append with all the queries it's absolutely fine.